# Rejected journal paper for submission as a book chapter

Tags: publications

My paper is not accepted in journal. I contacted other journals as well, but they considered it out of scope for their journal. I want to now submit it as a book chapter in springer or IEEE. Please tell if it is possible or not? Is publishing a paper as a book chapter equivalent to publishing in an impact factor journal? I want to acquire scholarship in Australian  university.

Comment: What is possible can only be answered by the book's editor. I doubt that many would consider it equivalent to journal publishing, but it would depend on the book and the process. If it has the same review mechanism, then it would have greater value than otherwise. But you need to ask the editor.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. Research papers aren't published in books.

When papers are published in books - so-called review volumes - they are usually by invitation only. The editor will contact the people who he/she thinks are able to contribute. They aren't research papers either; they're usually reviews.

You're probably best off talking to your supervisor about what to do next. It's unlikely that there are no other journals that will consider your paper; you just have to find them.

Comment: "Research papers aren't published in books." This depends entirely on the field. In philosophy, for example, research papers are often published in collected volumes.